# Sum of each row by a single formula

Tags: google-sheets, sum

Because I want to integrate the sum in a query formula, I wish to get the sum of columns B et F by a single formula.
I hav written tis one but far too complex

```
=transpose(query(transpose(query(B1:F,"select * where B  > 0 ")),"select sum(Col1),sum(Col2) "))
```

Is there a much simplier way ? I tried

```
=arrayformula(sum(offset(A1:A,,1,,6)))
```

but it doesn't work because this formula give me the grand total.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if((A2:A<>""),MMULT(value(B2:F),TRANSPOSE(column(B2:F2)^0)),))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Nabnub. Can I complete my question : how ca I do to get the average, assuming there is sometimes 0 as sometimes null

Comment: https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/average-across-rows-in-google-sheets/

Comment: Thanks a lot, indeed !